# Keycloak API works for admin-CLI client only

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I'm trying to get a list of users by a specific role using but I get a 403 forbidden error using a custom-client generated access token

`GET: http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/8cf0e750-6805-46e9-a9b9-a33b1340b175/roles/{role}/users`

The strange thing is when I use an access token generated by the keycloak API (`client_id: admin-CLI`), with the same user credentials (`POST: http://localhost:8080/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`) to get the list of users, it works!

The decoded JWT token structure is a bit different but I want to understand why the token generated for the `admin-CLI` client works and the one generated for my custom client doesn't.

Comment: Can you please add the roles assigned to each of the users?

Answer (score 1):

It is not related 'admin-cli' client.
It depends on user has a `view-users` role of `realm-managemet` client or Not.

That role can get the user list.

[image]

Demo `user1` get token with other client(`my-test`), can get the user list.
[image]
[image]

He can get user list without `admin-cli`
[image]

How to know a user can get user list?

This API can see the `realm-management` role mapping lists

```
GET {Keycloak URL}auth/admin/realms/test/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings
```

if a user has `manage-user` role, she can do update/delete/create user.

Same idea, `view-client` role, can get the client list.

[image]

Comment: @GerhardPowell, Keycloak V20 or high version needs to remove `/auth` path in API URL.

Example
New version
GET {Keycloak URL}/admin/realms/test/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings

Old version
GET {Keycloak URL}/auth/admin/realms/test/users/{user-uuid}/role-mappings